# Power series method to solve $(1-x)y^\prime + y = 1 + x, y(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n \Rightarrow y^\prime(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1}, y^{\prime\prime}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)c_nx^{n-2}$. Now:

$$(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = 1 + x$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1} -\sum_{n=0}^\infty nc_nx^{n}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = 1 + x$$

But I'm having trouble with the right side of the equation.

Comment: The key is that the two have to be equal _as series_; you should think of the RHS as $1+1\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3+0\cdot x^4+\ldots$

Comment: Group the left side in terms of powers of $x^n$, by shifting the first sum via $m=n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1} -\sum_{n=0}^\infty nc_nx^{n}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = 1 + x$$
Start at $n=1$ since for $n=0$ the first and second sum is zero.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_nx^{n-1} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_nx^{n}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = 1 + x$$
Now shift the indice of first sum $n \to n+1$:

$$\sum_{\color{red}{n+1}=1}^\infty (\color{red}{n+1})c_{\color{red}{n+1}}x^{\color{red}{n+1}-1} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_nx^{n}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = 1 + x$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)c_{n+1}x^{n} -\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_nx^{n}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n = 1 + x$$
$$c_1+c_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)c_{n+1}+(1-n)c_n)x^n = 1 + x$$
$$c_1+c_0+2c_2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty ((n+1)c_{n+1}+(1-n)c_n)x^n = 1 + x$$
From this you deduce that:
$$c_1+c_0=1$$
$$2c_2x=x \implies c_2=\dfrac 12$$
And the recurrence relation:
$$c_{n+1}=\dfrac {(n-1)}{(n+1)}c_n$$

Comment: The recurrence relation starts with $n=2$, right?

Comment: @Kira Yes you're completely right